# iOS - Trying to fade a view controller in

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

In fading a view controller in from black, I am doing the following within `viewDidLoad`:

- Creating a `UIView` with a black background;
- Giving the `UIView` an alpha value of `1.0f`;
- Adding the `UIView` as a subview of `[self view]`;
- Fading the black `UIView` out via `animateWithDuration` by changing its alpha value to `0.0f`; and
- Removing the black `UIView` from `[[self view] subviews]`

More often than not, this works as planned. Occasionally, however, I see a glimpse of the view controller I want initially hidden, just before the black `UIView` is drawn.

Is there a way to avoid this? Is there a better method to place this code in than `viewDidLoad`?

Many thanks

Comment: Why not just set `self.view.alpha`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add the view in the loadView method and do the actual animation in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear.  Or do as the above commentor said and simply use the view alpha.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the `UIView` that I want hidden in `UIViewController`'s nib file, then link that to via an IBOutlet

```
@interface SomeViewController: UIViewController
{
      IBOutlet UIView *blackView;
}
```

then in `UIViewController`'s `-(void) viewDidLoad;` method, I would do the following

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // Fade the opacity of blackView over 1 second, 
  // then remove it from the view controller. 
  [UIView animateWithDuration:1 
                  delay:0
                options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
             animations:^{
                 blackView.layer.opacity = 0;
             } 
             completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                 // This line prevents the flash
                 blackView.layer.opacity = 0;
                 [blackView removeFromSuperview];
             }];
}
```